# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src' even after adding path

Tags: python, path, python-module

I'm attempting to import some functions from src, but I keep getting the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'". I've added src to the path, but to no avail. Here is my directory structure:

```
my-project
  -- src
      -- __init__.py
      -- file1.py
  -- notebooks
      -- __init__.py
      -- current_notebook.ipynb
```

In current_notebook.ipynb, I am calling `from src.file1 import *`. However, whenever I try to run it I get an error. I've added src to my path using sys `(sys.path.insert(0, '/path_to_desktop/my_project/src')` and tried `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path_to_desktop/my-project/src`, but it is still not working. Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you should just add your project path to `sys.path` rather than the path to the `src` module.

Here is what it would look like:

```py
import os
import sys

# get the project path dynamically to avoid hardcoded path
project_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..'))

# check the path is not already in sys.path, to avoid duplicates
if project_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, project_path)

from src.file1 import *
```

PS: This [article](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/#modules) has a clear and concise description of how the modules are found and imported.